# Can't get fancyhdr to work correctly

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I am attempting to write a proposal using the following packages, fancyhdr, everypage and draftwatermark. Although the document prints quite nicely, all of the pages are lacking any headers or footers except for the page number.

I have began removing various items to see if that would resolve the issue, but at this point I am at a loss.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,everypage,draftwatermark}

\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{Waterville Oaks Properties, LLC}
\rhead{\bfseries Project: Home Place}
\lfoot{\today}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\rfoot{Callis \& Associates}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
```

Later in my document, I do add the following:

```
\setcounter{page}{1}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\newpage
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\listoftables
\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}
```

But that shouldn't cause any issues as far as my limited knowledge tells me. Any help would be greatly appreciated, because this is started to pull me away from what I should actually be doing which is writing and not obsessing over these formatting issues.

Comment: Works perfectly well here! I also copied and pasted to www.sharelatex.com and the output was as you desire. So apparently something wrong on your local machine.

Comment: It works fine here as well. Are you probably saying that you want headers and footers in chapter first pages, in TOC pages, etc?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to have the same headers and footers you have in "normal pages" also in "special pages" (first pages of chapters, table of contents, etc.) you have to redefine the `plain` style of `fancyhdr` package.

In other words, you have to add these lines to your document:

```
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\lhead{Waterville Oaks Properties, LLC}
\rhead{\bfseries Project: Home Place}
\lfoot{\today}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\rfoot{Callis \& Associates}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
}
```

This because the above mentioned "special pages" have `\thispagestyle{plain}` by default.

Comment: Or simply `\makeatletter\let\ps@plain\ps@fancy\makeatother`.